# Flask Admin - Automatically create password hash when creating a new user?

Tags: flask, flask-admin

Say I have a user model like:

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(255))
    last_name = db.Column(db.String(255))
    email = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(255))
    registered_on = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=True)
    roles = db.relationship('Role', secondary=roles_users,
                            backref=db.backref('users', lazy='dynamic'))
```

And an admin view:

```
class UserView(MyModelView):

    form_columns = (
        'roles',
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'email',
        'password',
        'registered_on',
    )

    form_args = dict(
                registered_on=dict(default=datetime.now())
            )
```

When I create a new user how to I automatically generate a password hash with something like bcrypt?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think by automatic you mean that it should automatically convert a manually-supplied plain-text password into a hash, but I am not certain. I am answering as if this assumption is correct.

We don't expose our password fields in Flask-Admin, but we handle the basic question of how and when passwords get hashed by defining `password` as a property with a setter responsible for computing the hash itself and tucking it away in `user._password`.

A naive swing at just trying to add `password` as a column in the admin view didn't work, but if you use sqlalchemy's `hybrid_property` instead of `property`, it looks like this works fine with `"password"` in your User view's list of `form_columns` (as you already have):

```
# models.py
from sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid import hybrid_property

class User(sql.Model):
    # ...

    _password = sql.Column(sql.Binary)
    _salt = sql.Column(sql.Binary, default=lambda: os.urandom(512))

    # ... 

    @hybrid_property
    def password(self):
        """Return the hashed user password."""
        return self._password

    @password.setter
    def password(self, new_pass):
        """Salt/Hash and save the user's new password."""
        new_password_hash = compute_new_password_hash(new_pass, self._salt)
        self._password = new_password_hash

# admin.py
class UserView(MyModelView):
    # ...

    form_columns = ("email", "password", ...)
```

The editing experience isn't exactly polished--you'd probably need to override the field to refine it. Here are some screenshots:

Creating a new user with a pre-set password:

[image: Creating a new user with password]

The edit view after creation:

[image: User created, password hashed]

Updating the user's password:

[image: Saving a new password]

The edit view after saving the new password:

[image: User updated with new hash]

Comment: What does the `_` that precedes password mean?

Comment: One other question, for your salt is there any advantages over calc on the application end or the db server end? ie `_salt = sql.Column(sql.Binary, default=func.rand(512))`

Comment: @spitfiredd Unlike some languages with strong access restrictions (defining variables and methods as public, private, protected, etc.), Python is very permissive. In place of those concepts, it has some [soft naming conventions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id36). Conventionally, an underscore prefix on a function or variable indicates something "like" it being private or protected. It's a warning that the writer sees this element as an *internal* implementation detail that external users of the library should avoid relying on.

Comment: @spitfiredd Because of these soft conventions, some Python software will treat things that follow these conventions a little differently. So, in this case, Flask-Admin will infer that, by default, it shouldn't include model columns that start with an underscore in the column list or edit forms.

Comment: @spitfiredd I haven't directly looked into using the database to salt before, but one consequence is that you'll be at the mercy of how your database implements it. The Python docs state that `os.urandom` **is** suitable for cryptographic purposes, and the docs for postgres note that the basic `random()` function is *not* suitable for cryptographic purposes; it also doesn't accept any parameter; you're just getting a random float back (though there is a salt-generating function in `pgcrypto`).

Answer (score 15):

The easiest option I've found is to add an [SQLAlchemy attribute event](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/events.html#sqlalchemy.orm.events.AttributeEvents.set) on `User.password` and hash the password there if changed. This way, anytime a user password is changed from anywhere, it'll be automatically hashed.

```
from sqlalchemy import event
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash


@event.listens_for(User.password, 'set', retval=True)
def hash_user_password(target, value, oldvalue, initiator):
    if value != oldvalue:
        return generate_password_hash(value)
    return value
```

Comment: Amazingly helpful! Thanks a lot

Comment: This was best solution to the issue. I just put this under my users model.

Answer (score 2):

You can set a `PasswordField` widget for the `password` field, and override the `process_formdata` method to set de hash.

```
from flask_security.utils import hash_password
from wtforms import PasswordField

class AdminPasswordField(PasswordField):

    def process_formdata(self, valuelist):
        if valuelist and valuelist[0] != '':
            self.data = hash_password(valuelist[0])
        elif self.data is None:
            self.data = ''

class UserView(MyModelView):

    form_columns = (
        'roles',
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'email',
        'password',
        'registered_on',
    )

    form_args = dict(
                registered_on=dict(default=datetime.now())
            )

    form_overrides = {
        'password': AdminPasswordField,
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Internally, `Flask-Admin` calls `WTF`'s `populate_obj` to set the data from the form.
So we can take advantage of that as shown below:

```py
class CustomPasswordField(PasswordField): # If you don't want hide the password you can use a StringField

    def populate_obj(self, obj, name):
        setattr(obj, name, hash_password(self.data)) # Password function
```

Then we can use it in our `ModelView` as follows:

```
class UserView(ModelView):
    form_extra_fields = {
        'password': CustomPasswordField('Password', validators=[InputRequired()])
    }
```

The password will be hashed the moment the form is saved.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Flask-Admin's [`on_model-change`](http://flask-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/mod_model/#flask.ext.admin.model.BaseModelView.on_model_change) and give it logic before it commits to the database.

```
from flask_admin.contrib import sqla
from flask_security import utils

class UserAdmin(sqla.ModelView):

    def on_model_change(self, form, model, is_created):
        model.password = utils.encrypt_password(model.password)
        # as another example
        if is_created:
            model.registered_on = datetime.now()
```

Comment: There are a few related concerns that come with splitting this logic up like this. I'll address each in a separate comment for ease-of-reading.

Comment: 1.) This only catches updates by flask-admin itself. If other views (like user registration/change password/forgot password pages) need to set the password, each one will need to do this correctly. If one doesn't do it correctly, there's some non-zero chance you might end up with plaintext passwords or incompatible hashes in the database.

Comment: 2.) It increases the chance any future developer using this codebase could mis-interpret the code. There's nothing about the password property or the User object that communicates this value should actually be a hash, and it won't be obvious where to look for more on how the value is computed unless you already know the admin view plays a role.

Comment: Awesome insight. Quick question, should I capture `registered_on` at on the User class level or leave it on the UserAdmin class as I have it?

Comment: We handle this at the User class level with something like `_created_at = sql.Column(sql.DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.now())`, but I guess the "should" part depends on whether you'd want that property set at creation for every user account.